# How to determine who owns a schema (PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL Developer, and I used the File->New->Table option to create a new table. After using the GUI to set up my table descriptions, when I click "apply" I get the error "no privileges on table space".

I tried googling a solution and I read that I need to give the owner of the schema privileges to modify this table. How do I determine who the owner of a schema is so that I can give them privileges?

Is there another solution to this issue that I do not know of?

Comment: The owner is whomever it is you logged in as, unless you specified a schema name on the table create statement.

Comment: You don't need to contact the "owner of the schema". You need to "contact" your DBA to give you quota on the tablespace. A tablespace is not a schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created the table, so it belongs to you, there is no need to grant something on schema level.

A different story altogether is the tablespace in which the table is created. There, you need a *quota*. With a privileged user, you can give the quote like so:

```
alter user <your-username>
  quota unlimited on <tablespace-name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need someone with sysdba privileges on the database your schema belongs to (typically a DBA) to grant your schema the necessary privileges to create objects (tables, procedures etc), along with a quota on the tablespace in question.